# Select additional rows depending on each row's value

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is: I'm trying to build a comments and replies system for my website. I already have this working, but the way I'm doing is probably not the best for performance.

I want to select 10 rows from a table that contains the comments, then I want to select 2 additional rows from another table that contains the replies for each of these comments. I do that by having a loop on PHP to select 2 replies from another table for each comment. Something more or less like this:

```
$comments = $MySQL->fetchRows("SELECT id, text FROM comments LIMIT 10");

foreach($comments as $i => $c) {
    $comments[$i]["replies"] = $MySQL->fetchRows("SELECT id, text FROM replies WHERE comment_id = $c['id'] LIMIT 2");
}
```

Like I said, I'm sure this isn't the most optimal way of doing it, since it requires multiple calls to the database. Is there a better way of doing this in a single query using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I often have 40 *well-tuned* queries on a single web page.  It is not bad.

On the other hand, `JOINs`, `UNIONs`, Stored Procedures, etc can cut down the number of roundtrips to the server.

Notes:

- A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` does not make much sense.
- The two queries you have can be combined using a `JOIN` and a "derived table".

  ```
    SELECT c.text, r.text 
        FROM ( SELECT id, text FROM comments
                WHERE ...
                ORDER BY ...
                LIMIT 10 ) AS c
        JOIN replies AS r
             ON r.id = c.id   -- Really the same id??
  ```

That will find all the replies from some 10 "comments".

To have limits on both gets trickier.